# Connect Inventory diagram to company correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]

I have a bug in my logic: I must connect Inventory table, everything works, but logic is incorrect.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are quite different.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by correctly?

Comment: And please explain by what you men by your logic. This is just a picture.